# Laravel 8 - Route cannot find controllers: Target class [Auth\LoginController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I went to take Laravel 8 for a spin today, but it seems the Route facade cannot find controllers anymore.

The route `/home` gives me this error:

> Target class [HomeController] does not exist.

I get a similar error when I run: `php artisan route:list`

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [Auth\LoginController] does not exist.

at C:\...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:811
811 throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
```

Comment: I had a similar problem installing laravel 8 from `dev-develop` but today laravel announced version 8 now released. may have been repaired. although I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Yes. This is a fresh installation of version 8, just released today.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks to lagbox, I ended up adding `namespace('App\Http\Controllers')` to the web route in RouteServiceProvider boot method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

That did the trick for me. Any better solutions would be most welcome.

Comment: Yes, It is working fine after adding namespace. Is it a bug ? `$this->namespace` returns `null`

Answer (score 9):

If this is a fresh install of Laravel 8, there is no namepsace defined in the `RouteServiceProvider` to be applied to the your routes. You can try to wrap the `Auth::routes()` call in a route group that declares the namespace `App\Http\Controllers`, or go about this in a different way. (assuming you have installed `laravel/ui`)

```
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers')->group(function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

If you want to know how to deal with the lack of namespace being defined for your routes:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808132/2109233

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly.