# Error “Target class controller does not exist” when using Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-routing

**Here is my controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        dd('aa');
    }
}
```

As seen in the screenshot, the class exists and is in the correct place:

[image]

**My `api.php` route:**

```
Route::get('register', 'Api\RegisterController@register');
```

When I hit my `register` route using [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), it gave me the following error:

> Target class [Api\RegisterController] does not exist.

How can I fix it?

---

Thanks to the answers, I was able to fix it. I decided to use the fully qualified class name for this route, but there are other options as described in the answers.

```
Route::get('register', 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\RegisterController@register');
```

Comment: welcome to SO .. is your controller inside `Api` folder .?

Comment: You need to regenerate the classes as `composer dump-autoload` or in your `RegisterController` is missing namespace.

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes

Comment: then try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: do i just type it in my terminal ?

Comment: Found a right way to resolve this issue: https://www.scratchcode.io/laravel-8-target-class-controller-does-not-exist/

Comment: Re *"the answer"*: What answer does it refer to? Can you link to it? Or do you mean *"the answers"*?

Comment: If you want to use resource route in Laravel 8 then use this:
```Route::resource('xyz', App\Http\Controllers\XyzController::class);```

Answer (score 599, accepted):

You are using Laravel 8. In a fresh install of Laravel 8, there is no namespace prefix being applied to your route groups that your routes are loaded into.

> "In previous releases of Laravel, the `RouteServiceProvider` contained a `$namespace` property. This property's value would automatically be prefixed onto controller route definitions and calls to the `action` helper / `URL::action` method. In Laravel 8.x, this property is `null` by default. This means that no automatic namespace prefixing will be done by Laravel." [Laravel 8.x Docs - Release Notes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#laravel-8)

You would have to use the Fully Qualified Class Name for your Controllers when referring to them in your routes when not using the namespace prefixing.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
// or
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```

### **If you prefer the old way:**

`App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
    ...

    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers') // <---------
        ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

    ...
}
```

Do this for any route groups you want a declared namespace for.

**The `$namespace` property:**

Though there is a mention of a `$namespace` property to be set on your `RouteServiceProvider` in the Release notes and commented in your `RouteServiceProvider` this does not have any effect on your routes. It is currently only for adding a namespace prefix for generating URLs to actions. So you can set this variable, but it by itself won't add these namespace prefixes, you would still have to make sure you would be using this variable when adding the namespace to the route groups.

**This information is now in the Upgrade Guide**

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Upgrade Guide - Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade)

With what the Upgrade Guide is showing the **important** part is that you are defining a namespace on your routes groups. Setting the `$namespace` variable by itself **only** helps in generating URLs to actions.

Again, and I can't stress this enough, the **important** part is setting the namespace for the route groups, which they just happen to be doing by referencing the member variable `$namespace` directly in the example.

### **Update:**

If you have installed a fresh copy of Laravel 8 since version 8.0.2 of `laravel/laravel` you can uncomment the `protected $namespace` member variable in the `RouteServiceProvider` to go back to the old way, as the route groups are setup to use this member variable for the namespace for the groups.

```
// protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

The **only** reason uncommenting that would add the namespace prefix to the Controllers assigned to the routes is because the route groups are setup to use this variable as the namespace:

```
...
->namespace($this->namespace)
...
```

Comment: This was really driving me crazy. The comment above the $namespace variable says: "If specified, this namespace is automatically applied to your controller routes."  Well it is NOT. You have to add ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers') as you pointed out. They should really change the comment in the source code...

Comment: @shock_gone_wild that comment and property were removed from the Provider about 25 minutes ago, so in the next patch version of `laravel/laravel` it will be gone

Comment: Why was the modification changed ? For Performance improvement?

Comment: the video version of this answer (5 minutes) https://youtu.be/MfE1tnMG6fE

Comment: With the newest version, we can now simply un comment `// protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` since `->namespace($this->namespace)` is used in the route declarations in the boot method , right? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @WesleySmith as of 8.0.2 of `laravel/laravel` that is there for you to uncomment and use if you would like

Comment: Hi, it's late but I am struggling to resolve the "Target class [] doest not exist", I am developing a laravel package, I did all good but when I register my routes with the right namespace, it gives me the error "Target class [CORRECT_NAMESPACE/CONTROLLER] doest not exist", can enyone telle me a probable reason? thanks

Comment: @lagbox The world is a wonderful place because of stackoverflow and people  like you...

Comment: Any reason why using `Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index'])->name('users);` would still return this error? Ultimately I used your updated option and it worked, but I am curious to know what happened.

Comment: Uppdate 2021. Use the New way as shown in the above answer. Works well in Laravel 8.

Use this
Route::get('route', [App\Http\Controllers\SocialController::class, 'redirect']);

Dont use this format
Route::get('route','SocialController@redirect');

In Earlier versions we just had to do "ControllerName@functionname"

But now we literally have to do [App\Http\Controllers]
Hope this gets simplified in future. Taylor Otwell is working really hard and has made a revolutionary framework. Love Laravel.

Answer (score 84):

- Yes, in **Laravel 8** this error does occur.
- **After trying many solutions I got this perfect solution.**
- Just follow the steps...

#### Case 1

We can change in **`api.php`** and in **`web.php`** files like below.
The current way we write `syntax` is

```
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@login');
```

That should be changed to:

```
Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'login']);
```

#### Case 2

1. First go to the file: **`app > Providers > RouteServiceProvider.php`**
2. In that file replace the line
   **`protected $namespace = null;`** with **`protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`**

   [image]
3. Then add line **`->namespace($this->namespace)`** as shown in image...

   [image]

Comment: Regarding the first case, what if we have a resource controller. that is , no specific function to specify?

Comment: `Route::resource("proxies", ProxyController::class)` fails with class not found error. It use namespace twice `\App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\ProxyController`

Comment: Thanks, this works like magic

Comment: I now get 404 not found

Answer (score 28):

The way to define your routes in Laravel 8 is either

```
// Using PHP callable syntax...
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index']);
```

Or

```
// Using string syntax...
Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index');
```

A resource route becomes

```
// Using PHP callable syntax...
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
Route::resource('/', HomeController::class);
```

This means that in Laravel 8, there isn't any automatic controller declaration prefixing by default.

If you want to stick to the old way, then you need to add a namespace property in the
`app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` and activate in the routes method.

Answer (score 23):

In Laravel 8 the default is to remove the namespace prefix, so you can set the old way in Laravel 7 like:

In `RouteServiceProvider.php`, add this variable:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

And update the `boot` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->configureRateLimiting();

    $this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 23):

#### In Laravel 8 you just add your controller namespace in routes\web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController; // InvoiceController is controller name

Route::get('invoice',[InvoiceController::class, 'index']);
```

**Or go to:** `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` path and remove the comment:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Answer (score 16):

I got the same error when I installed Laravel version 8.27.0:
The error is as follows:

[image: The error that I got.]

But when I saw my `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file, I had namespaces inside my boot method. Then I just uncommented this => `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';`.

Now my project is working.

Answer (score 11):

Laravel 8 updated RouteServiceProvider and it affects routes with the string syntax. You can change it like in previous answers, but the recommended way is using action syntax, not using route with string syntax:

```
Route::get('register', 'Api\RegisterController@register');
```

It should be changed to:

```
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);
```

Answer (score 9):

In the web.php (or api.php) in the routes folder, use/add that missing Controller class.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\<name of controller class>
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Laravel 8, just copy and paste my code:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Answer (score 8):

For the solution, just uncomment line 29:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

in the `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` file.

[Just uncomment line 29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtwSJ.png)

Comment: this one solved my issue laravel 8.22.1 .. none of the above highly rated worked. Thx

Comment: Very nice, I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: This line was not commented before, after comment this line issue resolved. Can you explain why we need to comment(in my case) or uncomment it. Laravel version is 9.

Answer (score 8):

The [Laravel 8 documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#laravel-8) actually answers this issue more succinctly and clearly than any of the answers here:

### Routing Namespace Updates

In previous releases of Laravel, the `RouteServiceProvider` contained a `$namespace` property. This property's value would automatically be prefixed onto controller route definitions and calls to the `action` helper / `URL::action` method. In Laravel 8.x, this property is `null` by default. This means that no automatic namespace prefixing will be done by Laravel. Therefore, in new Laravel 8.x applications, controller route definitions should be defined using standard PHP callable syntax:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Calls to the `action` related methods should use the same callable syntax:

```
action([UserController::class, 'index']);

return Redirect::action([UserController::class, 'index']);
```

If you prefer Laravel 7.x style controller route prefixing, you may simply add the `$namespace` property into your application's `RouteServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 7):

Also check your route **web.php** file if your RegisterController is properly in place..

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;


Route::get('/register',[RegisterController::class,'index'])->name('register');
Route::post('/register',[RegisterController::class,'store']);

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('test.index');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would like to continue using the original auto-prefixed controller routing, you can simply set the value of the $namespace property within your RouteServiceProvider and update the route registrations within the boot method to use the $namespace property:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));

            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One important thing to make sure you do after each change on the routes is clearing the cache (using Laravel 9):

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 8 you can use it like this:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers', 'prefix'=>'admin',
 'as'=>'admin.', 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function()
{
    Route::resource('/dashboard', 'DashboardController')->only([
        'index'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: This was helpful for a different reason, when you don't want to autowire all the 5 methods that Laravel creates with the `Route::apiResource`.

Answer (score 2):

Just uncomment the below line from `RouteServiceProvider` (if does not exists then add it):

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Answer (score 1):

On a freshly installed Laravel 8, in the *App/Providers/RouteServices.php* file:

```
 /*
 * The path to the "home" route for your application.
 *
 * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public const HOME = '/home';

/**
 * The controller namespace for the application.
 *
 * When present, controller route declarations will automatically be prefixed with this namespace.
 *
 * @var string|null
 */
 // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Uncomment line

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

That should help you run Laravel the old-fashioned way.

In case you are upgrading from lower versions of Laravel to 8 then you might have to implicitly add line

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

in the *RouteServices.php* file for it to function the old way.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the same error, because I forgot to capitalize the first letter of `controllers` in the path.

So I changed

`use App\Http\controllers\HomeController;`

to this:

`use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;`

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything, didn't work, until I tried this 2nd time
restart server

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize

php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to change my route naming to the more recently supported format, as others have mentioned:

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

However, it continued to give me the same errors, until I ran this terminal command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you prefer grouping of these routes, you can do it as:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Api'], function () {
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('book', 'BookController');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you're using the correct name of the file in your route.

For example:

If your controller file was named **User.php**, make that you're referencing it with **User** and not **UserController**.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 9, there isn't any need to add a namespace in RouteServiceProvider.

Instead of

```
Route::resource('tickets', 'TicketController');
```

use

```
Route::resource('tickets', TicketController::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when running `php artisan route:list`. In my case I had deleted the recourse controller yet the route was still defined. I had to make sure the class in question was commented off in my routes/web.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
    "Target class [] does not exist."
```

for me it was because another developer in the team added the middleware method to the routes group and forgot to write its name

```
    ->middleware('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the line

> use App\Http\Controllers\RegisterController;

in the Web.php file.

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 8 the way routes are specified has changed:

```
Route::resource('homes', HomeController::class)->names('home.index');
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this error:

> (Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\ControllerFileName] does not exist.

Solution:

Just check your class *name*. It should be the exact same of your file name.

Answer (score -1):

It happened to me when I was passing null to the `middleware` function:

```
Route::middleware(null)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/some-path', [SomeController::class, 'search']);
});
```

Passing `[]` for no middleware works. Or probably just remove the `middleware` call if not using middleware :D

Answer (score -1):

In the *app/Providers folder*, file RouteServiceProvider.php, change the protected `$namespace` variable to

```
protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

This will auto-comment the variable on save.

Comment: What do you mean by *"auto-comment"*? What happens? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

It is interesting to notice that since laravel v8, it is possible to use `Route::controller(MyController::class)`…
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-group-controllers

In my case, I change previous laravel v7 coded

```php
// CRUD Sample
Route::group(['prefix' => 'sample'], function ($router) {       // sample
    Route::get('/', 'SampleController@index');
    Route::get('/new', 'SampleController@create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/store', 'SampleController@store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/edit'], function ($router) {            // sample/edit/{number}
        Route::get('/{number}', 'SampleController@edit')->middleware('auth');
        Route::get('/{number}/{migrate?}', 'SampleController@edit')->middleware('auth');
        Route::post('/', 'SampleController@store')->middleware('auth');
    });
});
```

to less verbose (v8 or more… v10 in my case) :

```php
// CRUD Sample
Route::controller(SampleController::class)->prefix('sample')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index');
    Route::get('/new', 'create')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/store', 'store')->middleware('auth');
    Route::prefix('/edit')->middleware('auth')->group(function () {         // sample/edit/{number}
        Route::get('/{number}', 'edit');
        Route::get('/{number}/{migrate?}', 'edit');
        Route::post('/', 'store');
    });
});
```

then `php artisan route:cache`
then `php artisan route:list`
doesn't return anymore errors !-)

I don't understand why *->prefix* doesn't works each time, for example :

```php
// CRUD Licence
/* doesn't work
Route::controller(LicenceController::class)->middleware('auth')->prefix('licence')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index');
    Route::get('/new', 'new');
    Route::post('/new', 'insert');
});
*/
// works :
Route::controller(LicenceController::class, function () {
    Route::get('/licence', 'index')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('/licence/new', 'new')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/licence/new', 'insert')->middleware('auth');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, maybe need group into
\App\Http\Kernel::$middlewareGroups
its work for me