# Route resource not working in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, routes, laravel-8

I have a problem with the `Route::resource()` method in Laravel 8.x.
The error it returns is:

> Target class [Admin\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProfileController] does
> not exist.

[image]

Here is my code in routes/web.php:

```php
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(static function() {

    Route::middleware('auth')->group(static function () {
        //...
        Route::resource('profile', ProfileController::class);
    });
});
```

I could not find where the problem is.

Comment: Exactly what it says, there's no such file/class. Check if you named it properly and if you namespaced it correctly

Comment: I think you just need to change `ProfileController::class` to `'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProfileController'`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally, I found out the answer in [laravel 8.x upgarade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade). I have texted the controller name with full namespace, instead of importing it.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(static function() {

    Route::middleware('auth')->group(static function () {
        //...
        Route::resource('profile', '\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProfileController');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Run following step for clear route cache

```php
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Route::resource('invoice','\App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController');
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you followed the upgrade guide. There have been quite a few things that changed from v7 to v8.

To `App/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` add `$namespace`

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * This namespace is applied to your controller routes.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
}
```

You also find more answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808132/799176

Answer (score 2):

I also faced same issue with Laravel 7 latest version. See how I solved it:

First include this directory on the page 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCpo4.png)
use `\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProfileController`

Then call the full version of the route including the className like this

```
Route::resource('profile', '\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProfileController');
```

This will automatically create different routes for all methods defined in the ProfileController class. See an example in the image attached using TodoController.

Comment: Note that when this could works, the solution given in upgrade 8.x guide in routing section https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#routing is set to null $namespace property in RouteServiceProvider like is suggested bellow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63845754/route-resource-not-working-in-laravel-8-x#answer-65189944

Answer (score 2):

Running `php artisan route:list` , I was having the same problem.

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\CourseController] does not exist.

In my case , what worked was:

Changing the resource from : `Route::resource('courses', CourseController::class);` to `Route::resource('courses', 'CourseController');`

I didn't changed any namespace and I'm using laravel 7.2.

Answer (score 1):

So the reason this is an issue is because Laravel 8 removed the default namespace on the RouteServiceProvider.

If you want to use the `ProfileController::class` functionality you need to reset the `protected $namespace` to be null in the RouteProvider to match the base code.

Otherwise it will prepend the $namespace to whichever class you pass.

so change

```
protected $namespace = null
```

Then remove the `->namespace('Admin')` from your routes.php file

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8, First, you have to import the controller like,

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
```

And then use the resource,

```
Route::resource('profile', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController');
```

if you used it in class,

```
Route::resource('profile',[ProfileController::class, 'classname']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code, it seem that you are using class without importing so first you need to import profilecontroller in web.php file.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProfileController;      ## insert path profilecontroller 
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(static function() {

    Route::middleware('auth')->group(static function () {
        //...
        Route::resource('profile', ProfileController::class);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have imported the class

Comment: sure, your got solution or not