# Controller Class Exists But Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, controller

For some reason, the target controller class is not found even though it already exists in the correct path.

Route

```
Route::post('/send', 'MailController@send');
```

My controller path is App->Http->Controllers

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\SendMail;

class MailController extends Controller{
    function index() {
        ...
    }
    function send(Request $request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have already tried composer dump-autoload. I was using laravel framework 8.0 so I have also tried to revert and use 7.24. Still, target class is not found.

Comment: change to `Route::post('/send', [MailController::class, 'send']);`

Comment: Where are you defining that route? Does `Route::post('/send', '\App\Http\Controllers\MailController@send')` work any better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#failed-jobs-table-batch-support), `$namespace` property with a value of `App\Http\Controllers` is set to **null** by default, So need to define :

Change :

```
Route::post('/send', 'MailController@send');
```

to,

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::post('/send', [MailController::class, 'send']);
```

Or, Using string syntax :

```
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\MailController@send');
```

There is a detail [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808132/4575350) provided by lagbox.