# Target class [UserController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have started working on Laravel recently and I have installed Laravel Framework 8.5.0.

Following is my controller "UserController.php"

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //


    public function index(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

and here's my web.php in routes

```
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
```

When ever I try accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/users, It just hits me with following error

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
>
> Target class [UserController] does not exist.

Comment: Check if this question helps you https://stackoverflow.com/q/63807930/14066311

Comment: Change `Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');` to `Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');`

Comment: very good .......

Answer (score 11, accepted):

according to laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#high-impact-changes)

you can do it in two ways:

1-  Using PHP callable syntax...

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

2- Using string syntax...

```
Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```