# Finding Controllers in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some trouble accessing controllers from **web.php** and **api.php** in my Laravel 8 application. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8) post and I've been through the docs, from which I uncommented $namespace in the RouteServiceProvider, but up to now I've had no luck.

This is my api.php file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\SoapController;


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('currency', 'SoapController@show');
```

And below is the error that I get when I try and load the **/api/currency** route:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get this working if I've tried both explicit naming and uncommenting $namespace in ServiceRouteProvider? (also, I've run **compoaser dump-autoload**)

One consideration is that I've installed the **notfalsedev
/
laravel-soap** package to try and get SOAP support working, not sure if it is messing things up...

Comment: you are not referencing the class by its FQCN ... a `use` statement does not have any affect on a "string"

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8 it's a bit different from old versions you have to do

```
Route::get('currency', [SoapController::class, 'show']);
```

Make sure you import `SoapController`

Refer to Laravel 8 [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) for more information

Comment: Unfortunately even if I do this it still gives me the same error.. I have tried as both a string and fully qualified class name.