# Action not defined unless I put the complete namespace to controller method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-8

Hi i hope you can help me with this. I couldn't find an explanation in the documentation but I had this problem:

if I put the controller like this I got an error telling me the method was not defined

```
<a href={{ action('MovieController@create')  }}>Create Movie</a></h3>
```

so I get to solve it like this, puting the complete namespace

```
<a href={{ action('App\Http\Controllers\MovieController@create')  }}>Create Movie</a></h3>
```

My question is; **is there any way I don't have to put the complete namespace to get it to work?**

Comment: its not a path, its a namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a namespace prefixed to the Controller when generating URLs to "actions" you will need to define this in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

Also if you do not want the prefix assigned to your Controllers for your routes by default you will have to make sure the route groups do not have this `$namespace` variable used to assign a namespace with the `namespace` method in that Service Provider.

Reference for namespace prefixing in Laravel 8: [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8/63808132#63808132)