# How to use Form Builder in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, formbuilder

I try to use the following package in Laravel 8: https://github.com/kristijanhusak/laravel-form-builder

In the documentation it says the routes should look like this:

```
Route::get('songs/create', [
    'uses' => 'SongsController@create',
    'as' => 'song.create'
]);

Route::post('songs', [
    'uses' => 'SongsController@store',
    'as' => 'song.store'
]);
```

Which does not work for Laravel 8, so i changed the code according to the following post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808132/2192013

```
Route::get('songs/create', [
    SongsController::class, 'create'
]);

Route::post('songs', [
    SongsController::class, 'store'
]);
```

But now when i go to /songs/create i get the following error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
>
> Route [song.store] not defined.

How can i make it work in Laravel 8, which should be supported by the package?

Comment: https://github.com/kristijanhusak/laravel-form-builder/releases/tag/1.40.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error you get says that song.store is not defined which is right cause you had given it a name and now you dont according to the given code. Try this instead.

```
Route::get('songs/create', [
    SongsController::class, 'create'
])->name('song.create');

Route::post('songs', [
    SongsController::class, 'store'
])->name('song.store');
```

in your form you probably use the named route song.store