# Target class [] does not exist. in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I founnd this topic: [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8), so in web.php I wrote:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
//...
Route::get('/units', [UnitsController::class, 'getAllUnits']);
Route::get('/units2', 'App\Http\Controllers\UnitsController@getAllUnits');
```

But any time I have this same error:

> Target class [UnitsController] does not exist.

second address works but it's so long and ugly. Why first address doesn;t work?

Comment: Because you use `UserController`, but `UnitsController` is the one you need

Comment: Just add ```use App\Http\Controllers\UnitsController```

Answer (score 0):

change namespace from

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
```

to

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\UnitsController;
```