# Target class [UserController] does not exist Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, controller, laravel-8

I have a problem in route to access the Controller, i have copied laravel project version 5 to my project in laravel version 8, i have change the file RouteServiceProvider.php in my laravel project in to this

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

but still not working, the error message says "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [UserController] does not exist."

this is the web.php code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

// Auth::routes();

// Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function(){
   Route::get('user/profil', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@profil')->name('user.profil');
   Route::patch('user/{id}/change', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@changeProfil');

   Route::get('transaksi/baru', 'App\Http\Controllers\PenjualanDetailController@newSession')->name('transaksi.new');
   Route::get('transaksi/{id}/data', 'App\Http\Controllers\PenjualanDetailController@listData')->name('transaksi.data');
   Route::get('transaksi/cetaknota', 'App\Http\Controllers\PenjualanDetailController@printNota')->name('transaksi.cetak');
   Route::get('transaksi/notapdf', 'App\Http\Controllers\PenjualanDetailController@notaPDF')->name('transaksi.pdf');
   Route::post('transaksi/simpan', 'App\Http\Controllers\PenjualanDetailController@saveData');
   Route::get('transaksi/loadform/{diskon}/{total}/{diterima}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PenjualanDetailController@loadForm');
   Route::resource('transaksi', 'App\Http\Controllers\PenjualanDetailController');
});
```

this is for example the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

use Auth;
use Hash;
class UserController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
      return view('user.index'); 
   }

   public function listData()
   {
   
     $user = User::where('level', '!=', 1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
     $no = 0;
     $data = array();
     foreach($user as $list){
       $no ++;
       $row = array();
       $row[] = $no;
       $row[] = $list->name;
       $row[] = $list->email;
       $row[] = '<div class="btn-group">
               <a onclick="editForm('.$list->id.')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
               <a onclick="deleteData('.$list->id.')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></div>';
       $data[] = $row;
     }

     $output = array("data" => $data);
     return response()->json($output);
   }

   public function store(Request $request)
   {
      $user = new User;
      $user->name = $request['nama'];
      $user->email = $request['email'];
      $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
      $user->level = 2;
      $user->foto = "user.png";
      $user->save();
   }

   public function edit($id)
   {
     $user = User::find($id);
     echo json_encode($user);
   }

   public function update(Request $request, $id)
   {
      $user = User::find($id);
      $user->name = $request['nama'];
      $user->email = $request['email'];
      if(!empty($request['password'])) $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
      $user->update();
   }

   public function destroy($id)
   {
      $user = User::find($id);
      $user->delete();
   }

   public function profil()
   {
      $user = Auth::user();
      return view('user.profil', compact('user')); 
   }

   public function changeProfil(Request $request, $id)
   {
      $msg = "succcess";
      $user = User::find($id);
      if(!empty($request['password'])){
        if(Hash::check($request['passwordlama'], $user->password)){
         $user->password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        }else{
         $msg = 'error';
        }
      } 

      if ($request->hasFile('foto')) {
         $file = $request->file('foto');
         $nama_gambar = "fotouser_".$id.".".$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
         $lokasi = public_path('images');

         $file->move($lokasi, $nama_gambar);
         $user->foto         = $nama_gambar;  
         
         $datagambar = $nama_gambar;
      }else{
         $datagambar = $user->foto; 
      }

      $user->update();
      echo json_encode(array('msg'=>$msg, 'url'=> asset('public/images/'.$datagambar))); 
   }
}
```

this is the blade view for user.profil.blade for example

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
  Edit Profil
@endsection

@section('breadcrumb')
   @parent
   <li>user</li>
   <li>edit profil</li>
@endsection

@section('content')     
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="box">

 <form class="form form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
   <div class="box-body">

  <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" style="display:none">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
    Perubahan berhasil disimpan.
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="foto" class="col-md-2 control-label">Foto Profil</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="foto" type="file" class="form-control" name="foto">
      <br><div class="tampil-foto"> <img src="{{ asset('public/images/'.Auth::user()->foto) }}" width="200"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="passwordlama" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password Lama</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input id="passwordlama" type="password" class="form-control" name="passwordlama">
         <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
      </div>
   </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password" class="col-md-2 control-label">Password</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
         <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password1" class="col-md-2 control-label">Ulang Password</label>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <input id="password1" type="password" class="form-control" data-match="#password" name="password1">
         <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
      </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Simpan Perubahan</button>
  </div>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#passwordlama').keyup(function(){
      if($(this).val() != "") $('#password, #password1').attr('required', true);
      else $('#password, #password1').attr('required', false);
    });

   $('.form').validator().on('submit', function(e){
      if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){ 

         $.ajax({
           url : "{{ Auth::user()->id }}/change",
           type : "POST",
           data : new FormData($(".form")[0]),
           dataType: 'JSON',
           async: false,
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           success : function(data){
             if(data.msg == "error"){
               alert('Password lama salah!');
               $('#passwordlama').focus().select();
             }else{
               d = new Date();
               $('.alert').css('display', 'block').delay(2000).fadeOut();
               $('.tampil-foto img, .user-image, .user-header img').attr('src', data.url+'?'+d.getTime());
             }
           },
           error : function(){
             alert("Tidak dapat menyimpan data!");
           }   
         });
         return false;
     }
   });

});

</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: the error says that when you do what? looks like you also changed all your routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having error because you are defining controller namespace on each route in your web.php file (Such as **'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@profil'**) as well as setting value for protected $namespace variable inside your RouteServiceProvider.php (Such as **protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';**).

Now what you need to do is either define controller namespace on each route in web.php file or provide value for protected $namespace variable inside your RouteServiceProvider.php

You can't do both things at same time. Just choose what suites best to your situation.
**Either remove the `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controller';` from RouteServiceProvider.php file or remove controller namespaces that you have attached with each route in your web.php file. (Change `Route::get('user/profil', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@profil')->name('user.profil');` to `Route::get('user/profil', 'UserController@profil')->name('user.profil');`) and everything should work fine.**

For Laravel docs reference you can read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#routing

**However many people would get this error because they are used to define their routes like
`Route::get('/users','UserController@index);` and it was fine to define it this way in Laravel versions till Laravel 7. But Laravel 8 has changed this method and rather provides new way of defining Routes.**

- Using PHP callable syntax which is `Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);` With this way you will need to import the controller file into the web.php

  OR
- Using string syntax, which is `Route::get('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');`

Answer (score 2):

If it's not your namespace problem, everything you have done by far doesn't work, maybe it's cache problem

```
php artisan cache:clear; php artisan optimize 

php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have made the namespace and route syntax changes, but aren't seeing any differences, make sure to run
`php artisan route:clear` in the command line within your Laravel project's directory.

After a lot of searching, thank you to [phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3023353/phoenix) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71773605/21947870) on a similar question, as I was having the same issue.