# Target class [UsersController] does not exist

Tags: laravel

I am trying to load up a view, as simple as that. I don't know where to go I using composer dump-autoload that it was an issue with loading the controller however it didn't help.
The pictures show the project files[Routes file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzL89.png)

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgsmU.png)

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkNvW.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G10Fr.png)

I'm hoping to get some help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using laravel 8 you should pass controllers in routes in new way. This syntax which you try is the old one. Check this..

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Also you should follow convention and name your controllers in singluar form. **user** not **users**. Let me know if it helped.