# Controllers not working on Laravel 8 despite uncommenting in RouteServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, namespaces

I try to create routes to my `index.blade.php` page, i've made a controller "ProductController" using cmd `php artisan make:controller ProductController`, so in http --> Controllers i do have a ProductController.php file and i put this code in it :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductContoller extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('products.index');
    }
}
```

and then in my `web.php` i create a route using this code

```
Route::get('/boutique', 'ProductController@index');
```

However it doesn't work.

Firstly, when i go to the pretty url i've setup for my project at localhost using Laragon --> `Projetname.test` i get the normal Laravel Welcome page, but when i try to go to the url i've just setup like : `ProjectName.test/boutique`, i get

> "Target class [App\Http\Controllers\ProductController] does not exist."

After reading about the changes since the update of Laravel to V8 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8), i've seen that the update made some requirements for routes since $namespace prefix are not enabled automatically, but however that can be enabled again by uncommenting this line in `RouteServiceProvider`

```
// protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

I do uncommenting that line and then clear the cache using `php artisan route:cache`, however it still not working..

When i first started doing research about routes issues in Laravel i've seen many forum spotted out that apache Allowoverride settings in httpd.config file may cause issue, so i change it settings from `None` to `All` and then restart Laragon but nothing works.

After correcting label on my controller it still do not work, i try both methode (the old and the new one) none of them works for me, cmd keeps returning me :

```
λ php artisan route:list

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [ProductController] does not exist.

  at C:\laragon\www\ProjectName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:835
    831▕
    832▕         try {
    833▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    834▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 835▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    836▕         }
    837▕
    838▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    839▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))

  2   C:\laragon\www\ProjectName\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:833


      ReflectionException::("Class "ProductController" does not exist")
```

Comment: `ProductController.php`  `class ProductContoller` ... `ProductContoller != ProductController`

Comment: Not sure to get it fully, could you develop your answer ?

Comment: just read it, you should be able to see the difference   :-) the names are different

Comment: Now i get "syntax error, unexpected token "return", expecting "function" or "const""

Comment: use the stacktrace luke ... then you will know what line the error is caused by so you can know what to fix

Comment: It says in the cmd that there might be an error in Container.php:835 but idk what it could be

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 8 Route should be

```
Route::get('/boutique', [NameController:class,'method']);
```

So in your web.php file add

```
 use  App\Http\Controllers\ProductContoller
```

Then write your route like this:

```
Route::get('/boutique', [ProductContoller::class,'index']);
```

And I think there is a missing '**r**' in your "**ProductController**" class name

Comment: Yes indeed i've deleted my previous controller, clear cache and then made a new one with "Controller" instead, but now i have this error "syntax error, unexpected token "return", expecting "function" or "const"" also i don't need to use "use  App\Http\Controllers\ProductContoller" in my web.php if i uncommented the namespace in RouteServiceProvider ?

Comment: Also just before this error i was getting error 404 in chrome when going to ProjectName.test/boutique

Comment: isn't there a missing ":" in between ProductController::class ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the note, I fixed it @JawadBounaâs

Comment: I couldn't guess the cause of the new error, try to clarify it further if possible @JawadBounaâs

Comment: I do change my code as you've described but it still doesn't work, i still get the "ProductController doesn't exist" error and when i enter php artisan route:cache in cmd i get :  error at Container.php:835

Comment: but now i get back to my former error with ProductController doesn't exist

Comment: maybe i misunderstood the "class" part in the route ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out after watching a tutorial here on most common issues with new routing methodes on [Laravel 8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uq9HB27fssc) that when uncommenting the RouteServiceProvider, using the old method require to use the old route method too on web.php, so it looks like that :

```
Route::get('/boutique', 'ProductController@index');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
Route::get('/boutique', '\App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@index');
```

or use name route group and indicate the namespace

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function(){
  Route::get('/boutique', 'ProductController@index');
});
```

let me know how it works.