# Laravel 8 Admin controller don't work - in what problem?

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8

I have this route:

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {;
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('backend.app');
    })->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('/news', 'News@index');
});

use App\Http\Controllers\News;
Route::get('/news', [News::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/news/{id}', [News::class, 'show']);
```

I need to open link /admin/news - but I have error:  Target class [Admin\News] does not exist.

News class for admin:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class News extends Controller
{
    //
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function index()
    {
        var_dump('test');
    }
}
```

Can you help me: in what problem in my case?

Comment: Have you included a `use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\News` statement in your routes file? Check your `use` statement, carefully.

Comment: Cannot use App\Http\Controllers\News as News because the name is already in use

But if I need News in public part and News in Admin - what I must do?

Comment: Do you have two `News` controllers?

Comment: Yes. One for public part - for user. And second - for Admin controller

Comment: There is semicolon after route fn. i.e function () {; remove this and check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing route definitions between the 'older' Laravel 7 style and the newer Laravel 8 style. Pick one and stick to it. If you've upgraded a project from Laravel 7 to Laravel 8, consider refactoring to keep things consistent.

As you have two `News` controllers, you either want to use the `FQN` (Fully Qualified Name) of each or alias one or both of your controllers.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\News;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\News as AdminNews; // aliased

Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('backend.app');
    })->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');

    Route::get('/news', [AdminNews::class, 'index']);
});

Route::get('/news', [News::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/news/{id}', [News::class, 'show']);
```