# bind a route to a method (controller) in laravel7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I cannot bind the "contact" route to the "contact" method which is existing in the "TestController.php" controller

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your routes in your `web.php` ?

Comment: yes i did but that doesn't work

Comment: Huh? I mean please add the code for your routes to your question.

Comment: <?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/contact','TestController.php@contact');

Comment: Did you see here before? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the file extension when you define routes, so your route should be:

```php
Route::get('/contact','TestController@contact');
```

Then make sure you have a controller with that name in your controller directory:

**app/Http/Controllers/TestController.php**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function contact()
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

You can see a [working demo here](https://phpsandbox.io/n/tight-dawn-oy1a-gnyee).

Comment: @ToubaDjebli I suspect you have overlooked something then. Do you get the same error or different?

Comment: the same ! i am working with a video tutorial and it doesn't get the same result as mine

Comment: @ToubaDjebli I added a working demo link to my answer. Check things like capitlization of your routes and class names, they need to match. Also check namespaces match.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find running `php artisan route:clear` will solve these issues sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Run Command `php artisan optimize` will solve issue