# laravel 8 Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException. Target class [Admin\DashboardController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

im still new to laravel 8 and i have a problem that says the target class does not exist. i believe it have something with the route of some sorts(?) im not sure. i only follow the tutorial but this is the error that i get. this is what i wrote,

web.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
    
    Route::get('/role-register','Admin\DashboardController@registered');
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ensure the class `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController` exists at the correct location with the correct namespace at the top of the file. This should be in `app/Http/Controllers/Admin/` with the namespace `App\Http\Controllers\Admin`.
2. For consistency, use `[App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registered']` instead of `'Admin\DashboardController@registered'` when referencing the controller method. You might want to name this route too.

Comment: tried this and it works. apparently laravel 8 doesnt recognize the old ways, but by using this, it can run normally. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following.

```
Route::get('/role-register', 
    [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController::class, 'registered']);
```

Instead of:

```
Route::get('/role-register', 'Admin\DashboardController@registered');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct namespace i.e

```
'namespace'=>'App\Http\Controllers\Admin' instead of 'namespace'=>'Admin'.
```