# Method App\Http\Controllers\FrontendCourseController::update does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have created the web route correctly.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\FrontendCourseController;

Route::get('update-item', [FrontendCourseController::class, 'update'])->name('update-item');
```

and add a method **update**. Also, I have created **controller** correctly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\CurrencyHelper;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Models\Course\Course;
use App\Models\Item;

class FrontendCourseController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->middleware('auth');
   }
  
   public function update()
   {
       dd('Page Update is working');

       return view('update-item');
   }
}
```

But I keep getting this error message

> Method App\Http\Controllers\FrontendCourseController::update does not
> exist.

Despite clearing caches using

```
php artisan route:cache
```

[image]
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: try clearing cache ,php artisan route:clear but as per question you have cached route instead of cleearing using php artisan route:cache

Comment: @JohnLobo still get the same error

Comment: @Dominc can you show full controller code

Comment: @JohnLobo check above; I have updated the code above

Comment: every think looks good.make sure user is authenticated and once try clearing php artisan view:clear and php artisan route:clear .if still not working then run php artisan optimize

Comment: @JohnLobo I have run all, but still getting the same error

Comment: @Dominic Why do you need `use App\Http\Controllers\FrontendCourseController;` in route file?

Comment: @nice_dev, any suggestion?

Comment: @Dominic First is to remove that. Second is, try and run `composer dump-autoload`  and check again. Also, I have personally followed `Controller@method_name` syntax. Is your current syntax something new in newer versions of Laravel?

Comment: Something like `Route::get('update-item', ['uses' => 'FrontendCourseController@update'])->name('update-item');`

Comment: @nice_dev Get this error `Target class [FrontendCourseController] does not exist.`

Comment: @nice_dev The usage of the namespace is actually correct, see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files). 

@Dominic Are you sure the `FrontendCourseController` is located in the `App\Http\Controllers` directory?

Comment: @nice_dev I have added an image of the controller above, kindly check.

Comment: @Dominic What is ur Laravel version?

Comment: @nice_dev Laravel Framework 8.26.1

Comment: @EricLandheer Not saying it's wrong but it shouldn't be needed considering everything in App namespace is autoloaded by composer.

Comment: @Dominic I would love to reproduce but Laravel docs says me to install a lot of pre-requisite softwares to install Laravel 8.x

Comment: @Dominic Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8

Comment: @Dominic I have recreated the provided code locally into an existing project (Laravel 8.48), it is working correctly here. You could try running: `composer dump-autoload`. If that does not work, could you please check if the `FrontendCourseController` is actually in the `App\Http\Controllers` directory? Could you perhaps provide a screenshot of the directory? If the file is in the wrong directory, please move it to the correct directory and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @EricLandheer check screenshot above

Comment: @Dominic Sorry missed that, did you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @EricLandheer yes

Comment: @Dominic It seems to be a stubborn caching issue! If none of these commands threw a error, and you have tried `php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan route:clear`
`php artisan cache:clear`
`php artisan config:clear`
`composer dump-autoload`

I am out of ideas, perhaps someone else has another suggestion. It is working fine on my machine. Final thing: You could try and restart your local server? What server are you running, are you running anything like `OPcache` by any chance?

Comment: Thanks, @nice_dev, and everyone who contributed. I found where the issue was. The App folder was duplicated, I removed one, and it works.