# Laravel Controller does not exists

Tags: php, laravel

Im starting to programming in Laravel and trying to understood how the routes works. But it always said that the class "UserControler" that I just created it doesn't exist and I don't know why.

**Routes > web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/user',[UserController::class, 'index']);
```

I have this in the controllers directory that I just made with the artisan.
**app>http>controller>UserController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;



class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

I get this error:

BindingResolutionException
PHP 8.1.4
9.9.0
Target class [UserController] does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Comment: So basically i just miss to use the URL where is the controller, I was using the default route, thank you .

Comment: @danieski have you ever checked your laravel version please share with us

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to import the controller to your route files. Currently your `web.php` file can't resolve `UserController` class, because it doesn't know what it is. You can import it using the [use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) keyword:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController; //This line
```

Answer (score 2):

just add your class namespace lik:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/user',[UserController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: You can also use it this way
`Route::get('/user',[\App\Http\Controllers\UserController::class, 'index']);`