# Target class [] does not exist - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

When I add a new route in web.php to
Route::resource('doctor','DoctorController'); get the error is Target class [DoctorController] does not exist.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJ4wO.png)

Comment: `'DoctorController'` in quotes is the Syntax for Laravel 7.x and below. Please check [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8) for full details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Target class controller does not exist - Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

Comment: its all strings no matter what ... you can still use the old syntax you just need to use the FQCN instead of just the class' name ... check the duplicate for the answers