# Getting class not found error while loading a page in laravel8 , couldn't find out the problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hi I am getting class 'App\Http\Controllers\ Student' not found error when loading localhost:8000/students . Tried to rename classes every way but error exist still . tried composer dump-autoload but didn't work .
Snippet of my StudentController.php code is below =

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;




class StudentController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
    $student = Student::all();
        return view('student.index', compact('student'));
}
```

My Student.php file code below -

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'students';
    protected $fillable = [
         'name',
         'email',
         'course',
         'country',
         'profile_image',
    ];
}
```

My web.php code is below =

```
<?php
use App\Http\Controllers\StudentController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

// New era student profile details

Route::get('/students', [StudentController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/add-student', [StudentController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/add-student', [StudentController::class, 'store']);
```

Comment: try adding a blank line between the `namespace` and `use` in your controller. Sometimes it behaves oddly without one

Comment: you may find the solution here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8

Comment: @apokryfos tried it but didn't work for me .