# Laravel/Twilio WhatsApp Chatbot: 11200 - Http Retrieval Failure Error

Tags: laravel, whatsapp, twilio-php

I have tried replicating the whatsapp chatbot built in the below blog post using Twilio and Laravel:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-whatsapp-currency-conversion-bot-twilio-laravel

I have tried replicating this post twice. However, when I test out the bot by sending a message I recieve an error on Twilio saying 11200 - Http Retrieval Failure. Here are more details from the twilio error message:

Debug event SID

NOa58ef5b2f604abf9ea4718ea95d5ede4

Service SID

SM28801242e0831dd259f663885446f69f

Resource SID

SM28801242e0831dd259f663885446f69f

Timestamp

11:28am UTC 2023-Apr-26

Message

The URI scheme, of the URI null, must be equal (ignoring case) to 'http', 'https', 'ws', or 'wss'

I have tried using both ngrok and sail share to make the application available, however, both did not work. I recieve an error on both of these saying "500 Internal Server Error". Could anyone please advise what a possible solution could be?

Please advise if any other info is needed.

BotController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\CurrencyConverterClient;
use Twilio\TwiML\MessagingResponse;
use App\Currency;
use Exception;

class BotController extends Controller
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(CurrencyConverterClient $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public function sendReplies(Request $request)
    {
        $response = new MessagingResponse();

        $body = $request->input('Body');

        $content = $this->determineMessageContent($body);

        $response->message($content);

        return $response;
    }

    private function determineMessageContent(string $content)
    {
        $formatContent = strtolower($content);

        if (strpos($formatContent, 'hello') !== false) {
            $message = "Welcome to the WhatsApp Bot for Currency Conversion \n";
            $message .= "Use the following format to chat with the bot \n";
            $message .= "Convert 5 USD to NGN \n";
            return $message;
        }

        if (strpos($formatContent, 'convert') !== false) {
            return $this->formatContentForConversion($formatContent);
        }

        return $this->formatContentForInvalidMessageFormat();
    }

    private function formatContentForConversion($formatContent)
    {
        $contentInArray = explode(" ", $formatContent);
        $itemsInArray = count($contentInArray);

        if ($itemsInArray < 5 || $itemsInArray > 5) {
            return $this->formatContentForInvalidMessageFormat();
        }

        return $this->performConversion($contentInArray);
    }

    private function formatContentForInvalidMessageFormat()
    {
        $message = "The Conversion Format is Invalid \n";
        $message .= "Please use the format \n";
        $message .= "Convert 5 USD to NGN";

        return $message;
    }

    private function performConversion(array $contentInArray)
    {
        $amount = $contentInArray[1];
        $baseCurrency = strtoupper($contentInArray[2]);
        $toCurrency = strtoupper($contentInArray[4]);

        if (!is_numeric($amount)) {
            return "Please provide a valid amount";
        }

        $items = $this->getCurrencyCode($baseCurrency, $toCurrency);

        if ($items->count() < 2) {
            return "Please enter a valid Currency Code";
        }

        try {
            $convertedAmount = $this->client->convertCurrency($amount, $baseCurrency, $toCurrency);
            return "{$amount} {$baseCurrency} is {$convertedAmount} {$toCurrency}";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return "We could not perform this conversion now, please bear with us";
        }
    }

    private function getCurrencyCode(string $baseCurrency, string $currency)
    {
        $items = [$baseCurrency, $currency];

        $currencyCode = Currency::findByCurrencyCode($items);

        return $currencyCode;
    }
}
```

CurrencySeeder.php:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\CurrencyConverterClient;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class CurrencySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run(CurrencyConverterClient $client)
    {
        $currencies = $client->getSupportedCurrencies();

        foreach ($currencies as $currency => $key) {
            foreach ($key as $k) {
                DB::table('currencies')->insert([
                    'name' => $k['currencyName'],
                    'code' => $k['id']
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('/currency', 'BotController@sendReplies');
```

Comment: Are you able to add this as an answer in SO?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. The issue was with my routing. This was because of the changes in Laravel 8.x. Check out this post: [Error “Target class controller does not exist” when using Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/error-target-class-controller-does-not-exist-when-using-laravel-8)