# Target class [controller name] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, routes

hello im newbie in laravel,
i tried to display page in laravel 9.52. i made blade file, resource controller, and call it in routes
here is my route:

```
Route::resource('admin/portfolio', 'PortfolioController');
```

and here is my controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PortfolioController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        //
        return view("admin.portfolio");
    }
```

admin mean is my portfolio blade saved in admin folder views.

i check the spelling file controller name but, there is no problem. i named my controller file as PortfolioController.php
but it comes error when i tried to run it:
Target class [controller name] does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error “Target class controller does not exist” when using Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/error-target-class-controller-does-not-exist-when-using-laravel-8)

Answer (score 1):

For working on **laravel 8, 9 and newer version** you will have to modify your route file like below. You will have to import class namespace at the top.

```
***in web.php***
use namespace App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController;


Route::resource('admin/portfolio', PortfolioController::class);
```

or
You can also define route by mentioning full namespace path

```
Route::resource('/users', 'App\Http\Controllers\PortfolioController');
```

Comment: best of luck for your laravel journey