# Target class [GoogleAdsApiController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, google-ads-api, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to replicate the Google Ads [API Laravel Sample app](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/tree/main/examples/LaravelSampleApp) and port it to a Laravel Jetstream application.

I keep getting the following error: Target class [GoogleAdsApiController] does not exist.

[image]

**GoogleAdsApiController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Lib\V15\GoogleAdsClient;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Util\FieldMasks;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Util\V15\ResourceNames;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V15\Enums\CampaignStatusEnum\CampaignStatus;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V15\Resources\Campaign;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V15\Services\CampaignOperation;
use Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V15\Services\GoogleAdsRow;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class GoogleAdsApiController extends Controller
{
    private const REPORT_TYPE_TO_DEFAULT_SELECTED_FIELDS = [
        'campaign' => ['campaign.id', 'campaign.name', 'campaign.status'],
        'customer' => ['customer.id']
    ];

    private const RESULTS_LIMIT = 100;

 ...
```

**Routes/Web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\GoogleAdsApiController;



Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});

Route::post(
    'pause-campaign',
    'GoogleAdsApiController@pauseCampaignAction'
);
Route::match(
    ['get', 'post'],
    'show-report',
    'GoogleAdsApiController@showReportAction'
);

 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/main', function () {
    return view('main');
});
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: `'\App\Http\Controllers\GoogleAdsApiController@pauseCampaignAction'` ?? Or rather `[GoogleAdsApiController::class, 'pauseCampaignAction']` ?

Comment: Literally googling the error shows you a million SO results about this. My best answer is: [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#the-default-route-files) as it perfectly explains how to use it... But, either way, here is one that has your same issue and the answer is always the same: [Error “Target class controller does not exist” when using Laravel 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/error-target-class-controller-does-not-exist-when-using-laravel-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this operation

**Option 1:**

If you've recently created the `GoogleAdsApiController` or made changes to your project's directory structure, it's a good idea to run the `composer dump-autoload` command to update the Composer autoloader

**Option 2**

You can use this code:

```
Route::post('/pause-campaign', [GoogleAdsApiController::class, 'pauseCampaignAction']);
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/show-report', [GoogleAdsApiController::class, 'showReportAction']);
```

Still, if you are facing an issue then try this one

```
Route::post('/pause-campaign', [App\Http\Controllers\GoogleAdsApiController::class, 'pauseCampaignAction']);
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/show-report', [App\Http\Controllers\GoogleAdsApiController::class, 'showReportAction']);
```