# Laravel BindingResolutionException. Target Class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting the following error in my Laravel application at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/user`.
Please understand, this is my first ever Laravel application.

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class
> [UserController] does not exist.

When I am trying the following code in **web.php** `Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');`.

UserController file:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'Hellow dear user!';
    }
}
```

However, this works.

```
Route::get('/user', function(){
    return view('user');
});
```

The migration was ran and the tables are successfully created in the database.

**Environment:**

```
OS: XAMPP on Windows 10
Laravel version: 8.5.0
Laravel locale: en
Laravel config cached: false
PHP version: 7.4.3
```

The full error report is shared at [Flare](https://flareapp.io/share/bP96xk7Q#F32)

Comment: This question has been asked a bunch of times already; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807759/laravel-8-route-cannot-find-controllers-target-class-auth-logincontroller-d, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8, etc. Laravel 8 uses new syntax for Routes, the above is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this will work -

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;

Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'index']);

//or

Route::get('/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index');
```